# Getting error "The capture file appears to be damaged or corrupt. (pcap: File has 1847605831-byte packet, bigger than maximum of 65535)"

Tags: c, libpcap

I am getting error when i am trying to dump a packet in pcap file.

```
 {    
    unsigned char *ofilename = "packet.pcap";

    pcap_t *fp;
    pcap_dumper_t *dumpfile;

    const struct pcap_pkthdr *header;

    fp = pcap_open_dead(DLT_RAW,256);

    if(fp != NULL)
    {
        dumpfile = pcap_dump_open(fp, ofilename);

        if(dumpfile == NULL)
        {
            printf("\nError opening output file\n");
            return;
        }

        pcap_dump((u_char *)dumpfile,header,data);

        pcap_close(fp);
        pcap_dump_close(dumpfile); 
    }
}
```

HERE data is a u8 data[256].. its 256 byte data.. which has the packet bytes like this

FF FF FF FF FF FF 00 50 56 A8 11 39 81 00 0F FC 81 00 1F FC 08 06 00 01 08 00 06 04 00 01 00 50  56 A8 11 39 65 2B 01 0A 00 00 00 00 00 00 65 2B

But when i open packet.pcap i am getting *"The capture file appears to be damaged or corrupt. (pcap: File has 1847605831-byte packet, bigger than maximum of 65535)"*

Could someone pls help me on this whats going wrong

Comment: A simple google search will show you [this](https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/3243/error-message-the-capture-file-appears-to-be-damaged-or-corrupt) and [this](https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/8931/capture-file-appears-to-be-damaged-or-corrupt). Did you try those?

Comment: Yes.. but what i could see is when i checked the size of packet.pcap which is 590 MB.. !! i dont think this is valid size of pcap file..Its way too much..

Comment: I suppose pcap_open_dead(DLT_RAW,256) allows oly 256 bytes to be written.. but why is the .pcap size so much??

Comment: Where and how are you initializing `const struct pcap_pkthdr *header `? It appears uninitialized in your code. You'll have to initialize it and set the correct caplen and len.

Comment: will not pcap_open_dead initialise the packet header.. i tried to initialize caplen but i got an error saying "readable data being changed" so i changed pcap_open_dead(DLT_RAW,65535) to pcap_open_dead(DLT_RAW,256)

Comment: "will not pcap_open_dead initialise the packet header"  No, it won't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something such as

```
{    
    unsigned char *ofilename = "packet.pcap";

    pcap_t *fp;
    pcap_dumper_t *dumpfile;

    struct pcap_pkthdr header;

    fp = pcap_open_dead(DLT_RAW,256);

    if(fp != NULL)
    {
        dumpfile = pcap_dump_open(fp, ofilename);

        if(dumpfile == NULL)
        {
            printf("\nError opening output file\n");
            return;
        }


        header.caplen = 256; /* or however many bytes actually contain packet data */
        header.len = 256; /* or however many bytes actually contain packet data */
        gettimefoday(&header.ts);  /* I'm assuming this is on some flavor of UN*X */

        pcap_dump((u_char *)dumpfile,&header,data);

        pcap_close(fp);
        pcap_dump_close(dumpfile); 
    }
}
```

For one thing, just because a function takes an argument of type "{something} `*`", that doesn't mean you should pass to it a variable of type "{something} `*`".  You must pass it a *value* of type "{something} `*`", but it must be a *valid* value, i.e. it must point to something.

An uninitialized variable of type "{something} ``*", which is what you have in your code, doesn't point to anywhere valid.

However, if you declare a variable of type "{something}", rather than "{something} `*`", you can use the `&` operator on that variable to get a value of type "{something} `*`" that points to the variable.

Then, as indicated, you have to give that variable a value if you're passing it to `pcap_dump()`.  You have to set the `len` and `caplen` members of a `struct pcap_pkthdr`; the `caplen` member must be equal to the actual number bytes of packet data (which might be less than the size of the array if the packet isn't, in your case, exactly 256 bytes long), and the `len` member must be at least that value; `len` would only be bigger than `caplen` if the packet came from a capture done with a "snapshot length" value that discarded everything in the packet past a certain point, which isn't the case here, so `len` should be equal to `caplen`.

You probably also want to set the time stamp of the packet; I'm assuming you're running on some form of UN*X here, so you can use `gettimeofday()` to get the current time.  If this is Windows with WinPcap, you'll probably have to do something else.

(`header` must not be `const` here, as you have to set it.  It doesn't have to be `const`; it's `const` in the declaration of `pcap_dump()`, but that just means that `pcap_dump()` won't change it, so you *can* pass it a pointer to something that's `const`; you don't *have* `to pass it something that's`const`.)

Answer (score 2):

Kindly install "pcapfix" on Linux and run it on the corrupt file as follows

$ pcapfix -d 'file / file path here'

This will fix it.